# Use the Newton-Raphson algorithm to find all roots accurate to $10$ decimal places of the polynomials

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Use the Newton-Raphson algorithm to find all roots accurate to $10$ decimal places of the two polynomials $p(x)=5ix^4-(9+2i)x^3+7x+6-i$ and $q(x)=9x^5-x^3+7x+6$.

The roots, with accurate to $10$ decimal places of $p(x)$ are \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x_1 & =-0.6558705169-0.3199027972i, \\
x_2 & = 1.0945274740+0.1232933718i, \\
x_3 & =-0.4256573741+0.5466630341i, \\
x_4 & = \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

The roots, with accurate to $10$ decimal places of $q(x)$ are \begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x_1 & =-0.6957049603, \\
x_2 & =0.8321654615-0.6809729048i, \\
x_3 & =0.8321654615+0.6809729048i, \\
x_4 & =-0.4843129813+0.7708604977i, \\
x_5 & =-0.4843129813-0.7708604977i \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

As you have seen I have done this question completely for $q(x)$ but I am having trouble finding the last root for $p(x)$. I have tried $0,-5,5,1-i,1+i,-1-i,-1+i$ Can I have any help?

Comment: Thanks @Amzoti!!! I found the last one. $x_4=0.3870004175-2.150053609i$

Comment: What strategy do you use for the initial points? For the first polynomial, one should try either a subdivision of the circle of radius 3 (some outer root radius) into 20 points or an equal number of random points inside this circle. There will be redundancy and some chaotic iterations which can be reliably detected after 5 iterations. See https://www.math.sunysb.edu/~scott/Newton.ps.gz for details and better configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Try:

$$x_0 = \dfrac 12 - 3i$$

You should get:

$$x  =  0.387000417455406-2.150053608761572 i$$